# Unable to find file in GCP Cloud Build file

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to follow the example in https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html#Real-World-Example

Dockerfile recreated here

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I've tested this locally and it works. However, when I try to run this in GCP Cloud Build it fails on the copy step in the production stage

```
Step 9/11 : COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat app/dist: file does not exist
```

What is the reason for this different behaviour and how do I get around it?

Comment: Try to debug your container on Cloud Build. Add `RUN echo ....` to print things on Cloud Build output. The npm build shoudl failted for any reasons ; that's why you have no file as output.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Thanks for your reply Guillaume. Do you have any examples of what parameters I could pass to `echo` to help diagnose the problem?

Comment: Whatever you want!! I often use a `RUN ls -R ` to list recursively all the file that I have from a specific directory. It could be helpful to do that after your COPYs to what there are!!

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere so it can be any Linux command?

Comment: Yes, you RUN something. cat, grep, ls, echo,.... whatever!